# How to remove html tags in source code of ck editor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm storing the data from the `ckeditor` to a database.The data has html attributes. How to remove the attributes in the source code?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Is your backend PHP, ASP or something else? This question is very broad so you might get more gelp by providing some extra information.

Comment: i am using mongodb and nodejs for scripting